# Web (anchor) link to a Notes database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is there a way to create a regular web (or anchor) link that will open a Notes client and display a pre-determined database from the workplace?

Answer (score 3):

try this for a local database: notes:///[drive]:/[path_to_notes_data]/[database.nsf]

This will open the database in the notes-client.

Regards
Thorsten

Comment: The server on which this database resides is "HUB/Report", how would this fit into the syntax provided?

Answer (score 3):

Thorstens answer should work for databases on servers aswell:

```
notes://[server name]/[path-to-database-on-server]
```

..or

```
notes://[server name]/__[replica-id].nsf
```

The Notes client seems to replace "`/`" with "`@`" in the server name to create a server name without slashes - but the host name or ip of the server should work.

I believe that leaving the server name out (or specifying `127.0.0.1`) will use the currently active replica on the desktop - possibly with priority to local replicas.

```
notes:///__[replica-id].nsf
```

Some details can be found in the footnote here: [Specifying valid notesurl entries](https://infocenters.lotus.com/domino/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.designer85.doc/DOC/H_SPECIFYING_VALID_NOTESURL_ENTRIES.html)